# chrome portable in which file to change accept-language

Tags: google-chrome, portable-apps

I know I can change accept-language when I open Chrome Portable in settings but I need to do it in my python script. 
Does somebody know which file shoudl I change in chrome portable?

Answer (score 0):

answer is: 
    folder\GoogleChromePortable 33.0.1750.149\Data\profile\Default